# Why I can't draw a chart? TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I want to see the results of the regression with the graph. But it turns out a blank chart. 
I use also not dataframe just values. but the result was same. And the dataset includes 537577 rows

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

```
#1. kütüphaneker
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

# 2. veri ön işleme
veriler = pd.read_csv("BlackFriday.csv")
print(veriler)


#eksikveriler

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

imputer = Imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy="mean", axis=0)

pro2 = veriler.iloc[:,9:11].values
pro2 = imputer.fit_transform(pro2)
print(veriler)

#test-eğitim bölme
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(s,y,test_size=0.33, 
random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lin_reg=LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(s.values,y.values)


plt.scatter(s.values,y.values)
plt.plot(s,lin_reg.predict(s.values))
```

Comment: Something (you do't show which line) is trying to use a numpy array as a key to a dictionary, or member of a set.

Comment: what is s, what is y, what is your dataset. Which line are you getting the error at.

Comment: y: age (i want to predict the human's ages) s: includes their gender, occupation, which city they live...something like that. and i used linear regression r2=0.929 it is acceptable for me. but the dataset so long. there are 537577 rows. I cant see the real age and my predict results. So I want to draw. y and s both of them dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
plt.scatter([s.values],[y.values])
shuld work with lists

Comment: Doesnt work:(  The error continue. TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'